# Is there a way in logback.xml to specify file log destination through classpath:, without absolute path?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I've in my logback.xml configuration file this appender:

```
<appender name="FILE"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>classpath:addressbookLog.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy;HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
      </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <FileNamePattern>classpath:addressbookLog.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
      <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
      <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy
      class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <MaxFileSize>2MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
  </appender>
```

so that I specify path to file in which to print logs in a relative way through classpath, but it doesn't work, no file addressbookLog.log is created and written.
It only works with absolute paths like /home/andrea/.../resources/addressbookLog.log
Have you any ideas on how to make it work with classpath?

Comment: Are you saying that 'relative paths' doesn't work?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [Chapter 3: Logback configuration: Variable substitution](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution) told us the various ways to refer to the variable defined outside, e.g. `system properties` and `classpath`.

The significant configuration is creating a separate file that will contain all the variables. We can make a reference to a resource on the class path instead of a file as well. e.g.

#### The logback.xml

```xml
<configuration>

  <property resource="resource1.properties" />

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
     <!-- Here we can refer to the variable 
      defined at the resource1.properties -->
     <file>${USER_HOME}/myApp.log</file>
     <encoder>
       <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
     </encoder>
   </appender>

   <root level="debug">
     <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
   </root>
</configuration>
```

#### The external properties file (resource1.properties)

```bsh
USER_HOME=/path/to/somewhere
```

Please note that the `resource1.properties` is a resource which available at the `classpath`.

You may refer to the full version at [Chapter 3: Logback configuration: Variable substitution](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution). I hope this may help.

Comment: That's not really what he is asking. He wants to know how to use the classpath to specify where the destination log file is. For example, the log file in his example would be "WEB-INF/classes/addressbookLog.log" under Tomcat. But it could be in a different location in a different environment. I'm looking for the answer to the same question...

Answer (score 2):

`<FileNamePattern>${user.dir}/logs/addressbookLog.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>`

Comment: Could you provide some explanatory text?